# Dynamically initialize child records for unsaved parent object based on a selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have a problem which I feel shouldn't be as complex as it feels to me at the moment. I want to initialize child records based on a selection made on a dropdown in the parent form and then show these childs (at the moment always 2) for further filling.

There are several mostly relevant answers here and elsewhere around the web, but so far I have failed in building a working solution.

Main building blocks are as follows.

`game.rb` (parent)

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_players, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :scenario

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_players
end
```

`game_player.rb` (children)

```
class GamePlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :force
end
```

In a form for new game I have following dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :scenario_id %>
  <%= form.collection_select :scenario_id, Scenario.all, :id, :name, {},     { class: "form-control" }   %>
</div>
```

Selection from this dropdown filters the possible forces for game_players (each scenario has two opposing forces).

I grab the scenario_id in `game.coffee`

```
jQuery ->
  scenarios = $('[name*=scenario_id]').html()
  $('[name*=scenario_id]').change ->
    scenario_id = $('[name*=scenario_id] :selected').val()
    params = 'scenario_id=' + scenario_id
    $.ajax {
      url: "/games/prepare_players",
      data: params
      success: () ->
    }
```

And here I am stuck. Based on what I have read I am trying to fire up this action in `games_controller.rb`.

```
def prepare_players
  forces = ScenarioForce.where(scenario_id: params[:scenario_id])
  forces.each do |force|
    @game.game_players << GamePlayer.new( force_id: force.id)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Which again should render this in `prepare_players.js.erb`

```
$('[name=player-cards]').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'players', locals: {form: form}).html_safe %>")
```

Which should show the form for both players where it is possible to choose player from users for both sides.

```
<div name="player-cards">
  <h3>Players</h3>
  <% @game.game_players.each do |player| %>
    <p><%= player.force.name %></p>
    <%= form.fields_for player do |pf| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= pf.label :name %>
        <%= pf.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, {},     {class: "form-control"}  %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But as I mentiond I am stuck in the Ajax-call. My controller action is not fired and instead I get show-action with id=prepare_players. In `routes.rb` I have this

```
get 'games/prepare_players', to: 'games#prepare_players'
```

**UPDATE** As per Sebastiáns advice I am now hitting the correct action in games_controller. But as I feared, I can't add new game_players to my parent without knowing relevant id. It would be easy to pass the id if I just had one, but I don't because parent has not been saved yet.

I am using Rails 5.1.4 at the moment.

Any pointers guiding me towards getting this to work are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the route you're using for the AJAX request is being defined before any other, for instance a `resource :games`. If the route is after this one, then it'll fire the `set_game` method and redirect you to games#show, and there you'll receive an error like:

> Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Game with
>   'id'=prepare_players):
>
> app/controllers/games_controller.rb:65:in `set_game'

Note the `games_controller.rb:65:in`set_game'`.

Comment: Thank you. That moved me one step forwards. I had that as the last one in the routes.

Comment: Are you getting any error now? I was wondering what's the value or where you define `@game`.

Comment: That is the next problem. I was suspecting that I am not able to access @game defined for new-action. And I can't.

Comment: So I get NoMethodError when I try to call `@game.game_players` because `@game` is nil.

Comment: What's the context of this, I mean, I understand you're trying to create a GamePlayer record for each ScenarioForce, but why pushing to `@game.game_players`?

Comment: I want to create GamePlayer record for each of the two players per Game. One Game is a report of session where one occurence of Scenario is played and Forces in play are defined per scenario.

Comment: What are those two players? you might consider getting those two records to create theire relationships.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157753/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-thepanu).